# Lambda calculus simplification excercise

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus

Below is the lambda expression which I am finding difficult to reduce i.e. I am not able to understand how to go about this problem.

(λx.λy.yx)z (λw.w)
I am lost with this.

if anyone could lead me in the right direction that would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you try to find a partition of the problem where you'd been able to solve at least *one* part?

Comment: It may help to note that [lambda calculus is confluent](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4110/2012fa/lectures/lecture14.pdf) (Church-Rosser) under the full $\beta$-reduction strategy.

Answer (score 3):

It is better to remind ourselves the Lambda calculus precedence rules first. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4794330/9939883 for better details about precedence.

Application has higher precedence than Abstraction. Application is left associateive and Abstraction is right associative.

```
(λx.λy.y x) z (λw.w)
```

Since application has higher precedence,

```
(λx.λy.(y x)) z (λw.w)
```

Since application is left associative

```
= ((λx.λy.(y x)) z) (λw.w)
```

Applying repeated abstractions

```
= (λy.(y z)) (λw.w) 

= (λw.w) z

= z
```

Comment: Thank you, I have made some edits.

Comment: Thank you!  Nice explanation!